# Calling setter/getter in the same class in a Java program

Tags: java

I'm struggling trying with setters/getters I coded in my java file. Essentially how it should work is the `setPassword()` setter should test to see if the password contains numbers and letters and is at least 8 characters long.

The part of my code that is receiving the error is as follows:

```
public boolean setPassword(String password1){
    int temp = password1.length();
    boolean length = false;
    boolean number = password1.hasAlphabet(); //hasAlphabet is undefined for type String
    boolean letter = password1.hasNumber(); //hasNumber is undefined for type String
    if(temp >= 8){
        if(number){
        if(letter){
        password = password1;
}
}   

    }
    else return false;
}
private boolean hasAlphabet(String password1){ //hasAlphabet is never used locally
      if(password1.matches("%[a-zA-Z]%")){
      return true;
      }
      else return false;
}
private boolean hasNumber(String password1){//hasNumber is never used locally
    if(password1.matches(".*\\d.*")){
          return true;
    }
```

Some of my variables were defined earlier in the code so there is no error on those. I put the errors in comments on the lines that have errors.

Comment: You have to *pass* the strings, not call the method from String objects. The String class doesn't have the methods `hasAlphabet` and `hasNumber`: `hasAlphabet(password1)`

Answer (score 2):

You're calling your methods on a string instance, `password1.hasAlphabet()`, which is the wrong syntax. Java's `String` class would have to have a `hasAlphabet()` method defined for that to work.

You should be passing the string in as an argument to your method.

```
boolean letter = hasAlphabet(password1);
```